# Application manifest for 64 bit applications

Tags: windows, manifest

I have created a 64-bit Windows application, and would like to include an Application Manifest.

I have compared several DLLs of other vendors, e.g. shell32.dll , and saw that they set the value "x86" as `processorArchitecture`; example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly
  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
  manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    name="...."
    processorArchitecture="x86"
    version="...."
    type="win32"/>
<description>....</description>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="x86"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
</assembly>
```

My questions:

1. Is it really OK that a 64 bit application gets a manifest with processorArchitecture="x86" ?
2. <s>Microsoft [describes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests) processorArchitecture as follows:</s>

> Specifies the processor. The valid values are x86 for 32-bit Windows
> and ia64 for 64-bit Windows. Optional.

This is very confusing to me. Why isn't amd64 / x86-64 listed? I have a 64-bit Windows, but I do not have an Intel Itanium architecture.

*Edit July 2021: Microsoft has updated the description. The new description is: "Specifies the processor. Valid values include x86, amd64, arm and arm64. Optional."*

3. <s>Is it OK that, according to the manifest, my 64-bit applicaton depends on "Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" with processorArchitecture="x86" ?
   If my application "uses" a DLL like comctl32.dll for displaying controls, I assume it must be the same architecture, as 64bit cannot bind 32bit without a thunk.</s>

*Edit: It turns out that I made a mistake: I had looked at the DLL using the tool "Resource Hacker", which is a 32 bit app, and so I saw the 32-bit DLL through SysWOW64 while assuming it is the 64bit DLL. The real 64bit DLL contains `processorArchitecture="amd64"`, as expected.*

Comment: I've yelled at this MSDN article many times before and loath to document what is ambiguous or missing .  You are looking for `"amd64"`.  You ought to favor the other undocumented setting, `"*"`, it means "default".  I don't know of any case where the default is not appropriate.  WPF apps use it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think I can/should set the processorArchitecture for the Common-Controls dependency to "*" too?

Comment: That's what I assumed you were talking about.  Just omit it from assemblyIdentity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `processorArchitecture` attribute identifying your app is not checked by Windows 10. You can omit it.

The attribute must have the correct value under the `dependentAssembly` element. However, you can use `processorArchitecture="*"` for simplicity.

If you want to be explicit, `amd64` is the correct value for the x86-64 architecture. Documenting only `ia64` is obviously an omission in Microsoft docs. I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/pull/369) to correct that.

`shell32.dll` specifies `amd64` in my copy of Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and your pull request in regards the processor architecture!
When I checked shell32.dll , I made a mistake: I looked at the DLL using the tool "Resource Hacker", which is a 32 bit app, and so I saw the 32-bit DLL through SysWOW64 while assuming it is the 64bit DLL.